# Y.delegate execute twice on second click. How to stop?

Tags: yui, yui3

I am Using YUI3 and having difficulty to find the problem?

Here i have this

```
YUI().use("modules",function(Y){  
    function Actionfunction(e){  
        //doing some stuff  
    }  
    Y.delegate("click",Actionfunction, "body","#myid li");  
});
```

And when i click on li items **Actionfunction** execute once but on second click on same li item or other li item **Actionfunction** execute twice and so on.

**Actionfunction** should execute only once on every click on li item.

Comment: I stopped execution by setting if condition inside Actionfunction like
if(oldid!=newid) and setting oldid at the end of the function.

Comment: You shouldn't need that hack.  Can you post an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: ok let me code in jsfiddle.

Comment: [here is the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/TaEdf/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer 
[here is the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/TaEdf/16/)

showed the problem zone by commenting in front of syntax.

Q. What was the problem?
A. On every call of contextmenu, `Y.delegate` redefine because of that execution increases on click on li item

Comment: By moving the 'callingliAction', it works as you want. 
 http://jsfiddle.net/UwjuD/1/

Comment: @ludo : its confusing, problem comes when we use this syntax
contextmenu.show(callingliAction()); but in the provided link you are calling callingliAction() during Overlay instantiation.
i don't know why this contextmenu.show(callingliAction()); is giving error

Comment: The overlay instantiation occured only once (thanks to the check if (!contextmenu) ). 

But contextmenu.show(callingliAction()) are called every time you show the overlay.  This syntax is actually weird. You call contextmenu.show with as argument the result of calling callingliAction. As the overlay show method do not take argument. It is almost the same as calling  callingliAction(); contextmenu.show();

Comment: @ludo: ok, i got it. but in this syntax contextmenu.show(callingliAction()). Y.delegate inside callingliAction() should attach the fresh event on the selector.. am i right?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by fresh event?
But every time callingliAction is invoked, new event listeners are attached. But the previous one are not removed.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the delegate subscription is happening twice. I'd drop a breakpoint in the code that's adding the subscription and see if it's getting called in response to some other action, or in response to the first click.

Comment: You are right. As seen in his jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/TaEdf/16/), the delegate seubscription is done everytime the overlay is shown.

Comment: Move the delegate calls outside of the event callback functions. Put them directly in the use() callback. They only require the presence of the body element to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would load the Event module specifically for this example. I would also refer to `Y.Event.delegate()`.

[This (jsfiddle example)](http://jsfiddle.net/4DWzE/) works and is easier to read and understand.

I am afraid I cannot explain why your example failed since I cannot reproduce it.